# Can anyone explain what this transformation means?

Tags: vector-spaces

I don't understand

T: V->E

where V is a subspace of Euclidean space

What is the difference between Euclidean space and linear space?

Comment: Euclidean space is usually $\;\Bbb R^n_{\Bbb R}\;$ (and some few times also $\;\Bbb C^n_{\Bbb R};$), and vector or linear space is **any** space over **any** field (and also sometimes over any skew field or division ring)

Comment: so usual x,y coordinate system is an one example of euclidean space? Then, what does that mean that V is subspace of euclidean space..?

Comment: If you meant the *ordered pairs* $\;(x,y)\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R$ ,then this is just a common notation for the real plane $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ over $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: An example of a subspace of euclidean space would be, take $\mathbb{R}^3$ as our euclidean space, our usual 3-d world/environment we live in.  Take a slanted table that has its top passing through a point we'll call the origin.  The plane corresponding to the top of the table is a subspace.  For it to be a subspace it must *(a)* have zero, *(b)* be closed under addition and scalar multiplication ($u,v\in V, \alpha,\beta\in F \Rightarrow \alpha u + \beta v \in V$ where $F$ is our field of scalars), *(c)* be entirely contained in the original linear space.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, $T$ could be any function between the two spaces you mention, so I will focus on the second part of your question: what is the difference between a Euclidean space and a linear space, and what a subspace of Euclidean space is.

Euclidean space is an example of a linear space.  The term linear space refers to any set satisfying certain axioms; briefly, a linear space (over the real numbers) is a set where you can add any two elements of that set together and stay in the set, and where you can multiply an element of the set by a real number (rescale it, this is why real numbers are called scalars) and again stay within the set.

Euclidean space of dimension $2$ for instance is the set of all pairs of real numbers $(x,y)$.  Surely you can add two such pairs together coordinate by coordinate, and you can multiply them by a real number using the formula $c(x,y)=(cx,cy)$.  So Euclidean space of dimension $2$ is indeed an example of a linear space, usually denoted $\mathbb{R}^2$.

What is a subspace, then?  A subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear space which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So, it is a collection of pairs $(x,y)$ inside your Euclidean space that satisfies the axioms for a linear space.  This is not so bad as it sounds: subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ have a very simple description.  If $(x_0,y_0)$ is an element of your subspace, all rescalings (including the zero rescaling and negative rescalings) must be elements of the subspace, so the entire line through $(0,0)$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ must be inside the subspace, and in fact that's it.  A subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is either the empty set, the single point $(0,0)$, a line through $(0,0)$ or the entire space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Similarly for higher dimensional spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$, subspaces are linear shapes that pass through the origin: lines, planes, hyperplanes etc.  There are many useful ways to describe these objects algebraically (by linear equations), analytically (by parametrizations) or geometrically (by giving a finite set of vectors so that these subspaces consist of all the linear combinations of these vectors).  You should consult a good elementary linear algebra textbook if these notions do not make sense, because tackling linear operators between spaces (which I presume is what your $T$ is, and even if not, you do want to understand its linearization) certainly demands to become comfortable with linear spaces first.